Why do I have to give an alias to ROWNUM in the WHERE clause?
I was completing a HackerRank question on symmetric pairs and succeeded with the following SQL query (Oracle 11g):
SELECT
    DISTINCT F1.X, F1.Y
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            X, Y, ROWNUM AS ROW_NUM
        FROM
            Functions
    ) F1,
    (
        SELECT
            X, Y, ROWNUM AS ROW_NUM
        FROM
            Functions
    ) F2
WHERE
    F1.X = F2.Y
    AND F2.X = F1.Y
    AND F1.X <= F1.Y
    AND F1.ROW_NUM != F2.ROW_NUM
ORDER BY
    F1.X;

However, when I try to simplify it with the following query:
SELECT
    DISTINCT F1.X, F1.Y
FROM
    Functions F1,
    Functions F2
WHERE
    F1.X = F2.Y
    AND F2.X = F1.Y
    AND F1.X <= F1.Y
    AND F1.ROWNUM != F2.ROWNUM
ORDER BY
    F1.X;

I received the following error:
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Why doesn't this work? Why do I have to give an alias to ROWNUM?

ROWNUM is a reserved word; it is not a (pseudo-) column of a table or of an inline-view.
table_name.column_name or inline_view.column_alias is the syntax used to refer to a column of a table or an alias defined in an inline view. There is no ROWNUM column of the Functions table.
If you wanted to use a reserved word as an identifier then you would need to use quoted identifiers:
WITH f (x, y, "ROWNUM") AS (
  SELECT x, y, ROWNUM
  FROM   functions
)
SELECT DISTINCT F1.X, F1.Y
FROM   f F1
       INNER JOIN f F2
       ON     F1.X = F2.Y
          AND F2.X = F1.Y
          AND F1."ROWNUM" != F2."ROWNUM"
WHERE  F1.X <= F1.Y
ORDER BY
       F1.X;

However, you could do it without ROWNUM by using the ROWID pseudo-column:
SELECT X, Y
FROM   functions f1
WHERE  X <= Y
AND    EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   functions f2
         WHERE  F1.X = F2.Y
         AND    F2.X = F1.Y
         AND    F1.ROWID != F2.ROWID
       )
ORDER BY X;

or, using analytic functions:
SELECT X,
       Y
FROM   (
  SELECT X,
         Y,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY x, y)
           AS num_duplicates,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(x, y), GREATEST(x, y))
           AS num_duplicates_or_transposed
  FROM   functions
)
WHERE  x <= y
AND    num_duplicates_or_transposed > num_duplicates
ORDER BY X;

